# Conditional styling for classic and Lighting in Salesforce

Tags: lightning, css, classic

I want to apply style(code below) only for lighting users.

```
<style>
        @media (min-width: 48em){
        .pbHeader .pbButton:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
```

This is a css for pageblock buttons, and it is creating problems for me in classic.
Is there any way by which I can only apply this css to lighting only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check `User.UIThemeDisplayed` to get an idea if your user is in classic or Lightning

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' }">
    <style>
        @media (min-width: 48em){
        .pbHeader .pbButton:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

[Share Visualforce Pages Between Classic and Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages)